# The cause of uncontrolled camera movement in a mode 7 affine transformation?

Tags: c, sdl, affinetransform, perspectivecamera, projection-matrix

I am trying to implement a mode 7 effect with C and SDL2. Eventually, I hope to be able to do cool effects, like change the height and field of view. But for now, I just want to get something simple working. This is what I have so far:

[image]

My problem is that that upon turning, I seem to be heading in the same direction, even when I try to turn a different way. It's hard to get a picture of this, but upon running my code, it should become clear.

I am very confused why this is the case. My code is largely based off of [this](https://programandocoisas.blogspot.com/2017/09/mode-7-rotation.html) tutorial. I left comments in my C code describing the intent of each section. If you know why my attempt to emulate the SNES's mode 7 isn't working, please let me know. Note: to turn, press the left and right arrow keys, and to move forward and backward, press forward and back. This code may not work on non-Intel systems since I am depending on Intel SIMD intrinsics. I am using clang 12.0.5, if that helps.

Here is my `mode_7` function which drives the effect:

```c
void mode_7(const Camera camera, const Screen screen, const Sprite* sprite, const Uint8* keys) {
    static Uint32 local_buffer[height][width];

    const int height_center = height / 2;
    const Vector dimensions = vec_set(sprite -> w);

    for (int z = -height_center; z < height_center; z++) {
        const int y = z + height_center;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            const int reverse_x = width - x;

            const Vector rot_pos_3D = {
                reverse_x * camera.dir[1] + x * camera.dir[0],
                reverse_x * camera.dir[0] - x * camera.dir[1]
            };

            const Vector pos_2D = vec_add(camera.pos, vec_div(rot_pos_3D, vec_set(z)));
            const Vector floor_pos_2D = {floor(pos_2D[0]), floor(pos_2D[1])};
            const Vector tex_pos = vec_mul(vec_sub(pos_2D, floor_pos_2D), dimensions);

            local_buffer[y][x] = read_sprite_pixel(sprite, (long) tex_pos[0], (long) tex_pos[1]);
        }
    }
    memcpy(screen.pixels, local_buffer, width * height * sizeof(Uint32));
}
```

This is how I am calculating the position, direction, and angle of the camera:

```c
void update_camera(Camera* camera, const Uint8* keys) {
    if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT]) {
        if ((camera -> angle -= camera -> v_turn) < 0.0) camera -> angle = two_pi;
    }
    if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT]) {
        if ((camera -> angle += camera -> v_turn) > two_pi) camera -> angle = 0.0;
    }

    camera -> dir = (Vector) {cos(camera -> angle), sin(camera -> angle)};
    const Vector forward_movement = vec_mul(camera -> dir, vec_set(camera -> v_move));
    
    Vector movement = {0.0, 0.0};
    if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_UP])
        movement = vec_add(movement, forward_movement);
    if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN])
        movement = vec_sub(movement, forward_movement);

    camera -> pos = vec_add(camera -> pos, movement);
}
```

All of the code, including the code above, is below if you want to try it out.

```c
// SDL2 header, handy macros, constants, typedefs

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define FAIL(...) {fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); exit(1);}

#define vec_set _mm_set1_pd
#define vec_add _mm_add_pd
#define vec_sub _mm_sub_pd
#define vec_mul _mm_mul_pd
#define vec_div _mm_div_pd

const double two_pi = M_PI * 2.0;

enum {
    fps = 60, width = 800, height = 600,
    pixel_format = SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, pixel_format_bpp = 4
};

typedef SDL_Surface Sprite;
typedef __m128d Vector;

typedef struct {
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    SDL_Texture* buffer;
    SDL_PixelFormat* pixel_format;
    void* pixels;
    int pixel_pitch;
} Screen;

typedef struct {
    Vector pos, dir;
    double angle;
    const double v_move, v_turn;
} Camera;

// abstraction for the screen

Screen init_screen(void) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER) < 0)
        FAIL("Could not initialize SDL\n");

    SDL_SetHintWithPriority(SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC, "1", SDL_HINT_OVERRIDE);

    Screen screen;
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(width, height, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED, &screen.window, &screen.renderer);
    screen.buffer = SDL_CreateTexture(screen.renderer, pixel_format, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, width, height);
    screen.pixel_format = SDL_AllocFormat(pixel_format);

    SDL_SetWindowTitle(screen.window, "Mode 7");
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(screen.renderer, NULL);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(screen.renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    return screen;
}

void deinit_screen(const Screen screen) {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(screen.window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(screen.renderer);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(screen.buffer);
    SDL_FreeFormat(screen.pixel_format);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void clear_screen(Screen* const screen) {
    SDL_LockTexture(screen -> buffer, NULL, &screen -> pixels, &screen -> pixel_pitch);
}

void refresh_screen(const Screen screen, const Uint32 before) {
    SDL_UnlockTexture(screen.buffer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(screen.renderer, screen.buffer, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(screen.renderer);

    const int wait = fps / 1000 - (SDL_GetTicks() - before);
    if (wait > 0) SDL_Delay(wait);
}

// abstraction for sprites

Sprite* init_sprite(const char* const path, const SDL_PixelFormat* pixel_format) {
    SDL_Surface* const unconverted_surface = SDL_LoadBMP(path);
    if (unconverted_surface == NULL) FAIL("Could not load a sprite of path %s\n", path);

    SDL_Surface* const converted_surface = SDL_ConvertSurface(unconverted_surface, pixel_format, 0);
    if (converted_surface == NULL) FAIL("Could not convert a sprite's surface type: %s\n", path);
    SDL_FreeSurface(unconverted_surface);
    SDL_LockSurface(converted_surface);

    return converted_surface;
}

void deinit_sprite(Sprite* sprite) {
    SDL_UnlockSurface(sprite);
    SDL_FreeSurface(sprite);
}

Uint32 read_sprite_pixel(const Sprite* sprite, const int x, const int y) {
    return *(Uint32*) ((Uint8*) sprite -> pixels + y * sprite -> pitch + x * pixel_format_bpp);
}

// the core of my code

void mode_7(const Camera camera, const Screen screen, const Sprite* sprite, const Uint8* keys) {
    static Uint32 local_buffer[height][width];

    const int height_center = height / 2;
    const Vector dimensions = vec_set(sprite -> w);

    for (int z = -height_center; z < height_center; z++) {
        const int y = z + height_center;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            const int reverse_x = width - x;

            const Vector rot_pos_3D = {
                reverse_x * camera.dir[1] + x * camera.dir[0],
                reverse_x * camera.dir[0] - x * camera.dir[1]
            };

            const Vector pos_2D = vec_add(camera.pos, vec_div(rot_pos_3D, vec_set(z)));
            const Vector floor_pos_2D = {floor(pos_2D[0]), floor(pos_2D[1])};
            const Vector tex_pos = vec_mul(vec_sub(pos_2D, floor_pos_2D), dimensions);

            local_buffer[y][x] = read_sprite_pixel(sprite, (long) tex_pos[0], (long) tex_pos[1]);
        }
    }
    memcpy(screen.pixels, local_buffer, width * height * sizeof(Uint32));
}

// input reading + main

void update_camera(Camera* camera, const Uint8* keys) {
    if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT]) {
        if ((camera -> angle -= camera -> v_turn) < 0.0) camera -> angle = two_pi;
    }
    if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT]) {
        if ((camera -> angle += camera -> v_turn) > two_pi) camera -> angle = 0.0;
    }

    camera -> dir = (Vector) {cos(camera -> angle), sin(camera -> angle)};
    const Vector forward_movement = vec_mul(camera -> dir, vec_set(camera -> v_move));
    
    Vector movement = {0.0, 0.0};
    if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_UP])
        movement = vec_add(movement, forward_movement);
    if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN])
        movement = vec_sub(movement, forward_movement);

    camera -> pos = vec_add(camera -> pos, movement);
}

int main(void) {
    Screen screen = init_screen();
    Sprite* sprite = init_sprite("../assets/dirt.bmp", screen.pixel_format);
    Camera camera = {{0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}, 0.0, 0.1, 0.05};

    const Uint8* keys = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    SDL_Event event;
    while (1) {
        const Uint32 before = SDL_GetTicks();
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                deinit_sprite(sprite);
                deinit_screen(screen);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        update_camera(&camera, keys);
        clear_screen(&screen);
        mode_7(camera, screen, sprite, keys);
        refresh_screen(screen, before);
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Yunnosch I just restructured my question to make it focused on just the problem with turning.

Comment: Can you turn as expected in a simpler program? I.e. how close do you need to go towards a SDL/OpenGL HelloWorld to get it right? Or to put it differently https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: @Yunnosch I just put the snippet which is causing the problem first - that way, there's more focus on what's wrong with my algorithm than with anything related to SDL and C. Let me know if you have any more feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues with your code.
One part is:

```
const Vector rot_pos_3D = {
    reverse_x * camera.dir[1] + x * camera.dir[0],
    reverse_x * camera.dir[0] - x * camera.dir[1]
};
```

This part is supposed to does more or less linear interpolation between two points when x changes from `0` to `width`. One is located at `camera.dir` pointing forward. The other one is pointing to orthogonal direction `{camera.dir[1], -camera.dir[0]}`.

See the image below:
[image]

However, it looks that the coordinates are swapped. It should be:

```
const Vector rot_pos_3D = {
    reverse_x * camera.dir[0] - x * camera.dir[1],
    reverse_x * camera.dir[1] + x * camera.dir[0],
};
```

Now navigation becomes less chaotic. However,the players eye always look to front-left direction as on image above.

A simple solution to the problem is to place the screen in the front of the player between points (FORWARD+LEFT) and (FORWARD-LEFT) points as on image below.

[image]

This fix is applied with following patch:

```
@@ -107,6 +107,8 @@ void mode_7(const Camera camera, const Screen screen, const Sprite* sprite, cons
     const int height_center = height / 2;
     const Vector dimensions = vec_set(sprite -> w);
 
+    double d0[2] = {camera.dir[0] + camera.dir[1], camera.dir[1] - camera.dir[0]};
+    double d1[2] = {camera.dir[0] - camera.dir[1], camera.dir[1] + camera.dir[0]};
     for (int z = -height_center; z < height_center; z++) {
         const int y = z + height_center;
 
@@ -114,11 +116,11 @@ void mode_7(const Camera camera, const Screen screen, const Sprite* sprite, cons
             const int reverse_x = width - x;
 
             const Vector rot_pos_3D = {
-                reverse_x * camera.dir[1] + x * camera.dir[0],
-                reverse_x * camera.dir[0] - x * camera.dir[1]
+                reverse_x * d0[0] + x * d1[0],
+                reverse_x * d0[1] + x * d1[1],
             };
```

The other issue is "ceiling" moving in the opposite direction. It is caused by dividing by negative "z"  in  upper part of the screen. Just apply `abs()`:

```
-            const Vector pos_2D = vec_add(camera.pos, vec_div(rot_pos_3D, vec_set(z)));
+            const Vector pos_2D = vec_add(camera.pos, vec_div(rot_pos_3D, vec_set(abs(z))));
```

Now the infinite room should be rendered correctly.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This is great. I have one other question: do you know how I could change the field of view here?